# No heat but fan and blower continuous run

Tags: heating

I have a Trane gas pack 1998 unit that heats with propane. The fan and blower are running, but there's no heat blowing in vents: just cold air. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The high limit switch is dead.  Contact a local HVAC contractor for a replacement. While you're at it, replace the air filter on the furnace. Dirty filters are the number one cause of premature high limit failure.